# Mixing button groups and input groups on the same line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a toolbar that contains a number of button groups as well as one input (for a date field). I can't seem to find a way to get this to work in such a way that elements stay aligned on the same line.

Here is an extract of the toolbar I am trying to get to work:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="date" name="date" size="4" >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Now</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">All</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn">Active items</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Archive</button>
</div>
```

I have created a Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/lsvPD6yC7H8xRe4JsFdR

I tried various combinations, including cutting all button groups of the toolbar in different columns, which makes things worse and does not work either.

I'm wondering if this behaviour can be achieved at all, or if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so (note the addition of the class `ig-mid-btn` to the 'Now' button):

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="date" name="date" size="4">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ig-mid-btn">Now</button>
            </span>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">All</button>
            </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn">Active items</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Archive</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.ig-mid-btn{
    border-radius:0;
    border-left:0 none transparent;
}
```

See [this demo bootply](http://www.bootply.com/NkMYa8nwim)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't managed to get this to work in the context of the application, but I got it to work on a fresh slate. Something (I don't know what yet) is leading the input field to behave quite strangely. I hope to be able to find what it is due to soon.

Comment: After applying the suggested changes, still had to upgrade to bootstrap 3.3.1 as this is broken in  3.1.1.